# Update a controller model in angularjs in a directive

Tags: model-view-controller, angularjs

I tried to understand angularJS, which has a different approach from what I have seen with its dirty check model update.

Basically, I have a **directive** `ng-draggable` which make elements... draggable. I have a **model** linking with each of this element with attribute `x` and `y` – the position of the element linked with the model – and I want the directive to update the model.

To do so, I tried to use the `$apply` function in my directive and set the model value x and y. Then I also use the `$observe` function to update the view: [here is my jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Yannik/pCLNb/1/). *(Note I use a factory to catch the mouse event)*

```
        var mousemove = function(event) {
           var y = event.screenY - startY;
           var x = event.screenX - startX;
              scope.$apply(function(){
                  attr.$set('ngModel', {'x': x, 'y': y});
              });
         }
```

It seems to work fine. However when I check the model value with the save button (it prints the model in the console), the position x and y are not updated.

So my question is how do I make it work? And more generally what is happening here? Any reading suggestion around the MVC pattern in angularJS (I found the Developer guide a bit harsh for a beginner)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem on your approach is that you are changing the entire `ngModel` reference instead of changing just one of its properties (`x` and/or `y`). When you do that, you loose the connection to the initial `ngModel` (objects inside `players` array) and consequently the connection to the 'real' model (object `play`).

Try doing it like this:

```
scope.$apply(function() {                 
    model.$modelValue.x = event.screenX - startX;
    model.$modelValue.y = event.screenY - startY;
});
```

**jsFiddle:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/y7nVJ/

Comment: Thank you! To be sure to understand you well; the ngModel that is passed in my directive is not the current model, but if I understand the [API doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController), a kind of "instant" controller that let modify my model?

Comment: The `ngModel` that you initially pass to the directive is the correct one, the problem is that you are replacing it by a new Object created inside the directive. It's like if you were doing `model.$modelValue = new Object();` which causes `$modelValue` to no longer be referencing an element inside `players` array (the initial `ngModel`) but instead be referencing the new Object you just created.

Comment: Ah! Ok, now I think I'm getting it... thank you for your precision.